# How to make a WPF button vibrate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-core-3.0

I am building a Windows WPF application that contains number of buttons.
I want to notify the user that he should load a pdf before he can press other buttons by making the load pdf button blink / vibrate if the user clicks on other places and no pdf is loaded.

For example - The exact behavior happens on Microsoft Paint if you try to click anywhere outside of the edit colors box while it is open. (see attached gif)

Does anyone have an idea ?

[image]

Comment: You want to create a XAML animation with a storyboard, and have a trigger/event associated to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: "The exact behavior happens on Microsoft Paint if you try to click anywhere outside of the edit colors box while it is open" - that is a default behavior of any modal dialog in Windows. Not related to Paint specifically

Comment: It's not 'vibrating', it's flashing the border.  This is normal behaviour when clicking outside of a modal dialog box.  If you want to replicate it outside of this scenario, look up FlashWindow or FlashWindowEx

Comment: @Neil ArcTicker wants to replicate the behavior not with a popup window but with a button.

Comment: @Soleil & Neil Thank you, I'll start to explore according to your answers.

Comment: @ASh - Microsoft Paint was given as an example.

Comment: BTW @ArcTicker do you know that the button gets deactivated when you bind to `ICommand` and when the command cannot execute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a storyboard with a `DoubleAnimation`, change the drop shadow, make it go back automatically and repeat it (here 4 times).

Here is a `UserControl`, which you can reuse for all buttons with such effect; you only need to replace the text "Button content" by some `DependencyProperty` to make it versatile.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AnimateDropShadow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            Button content
            <Button.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect x:Name="warningEffect" Color="Black" BlurRadius="10"  ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Button.Effect>
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="warningEffect"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius"
                                From="15" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="0:0:0.4" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```